# GET COLOR OF POINT

Tags: vb6

I want to write code in vb6
When the form is placed on the screen. and when click Button Return the colors me.top and me.left position.
I want this to be real-time(use timer)

my code:

```
Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Label3 = (GetPixel(GetDC(Me.hdc), Me.Left, Me.Top))
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
Label1.Caption = Me.Left
Label2.Caption = Me.Top

End Sub
```

This code does not work and returns a value of -1

please help me

Comment: You are using `Me.hdc` instead of `Me.hWnd`. Which you don't need to use at all, because `GetDC(Me.hwnd)` would give you `Me.hdc`.

Comment: The color of what point?  The color of the point below the form?

Comment: yes i want get color below the form in any position

Answer (score 1):

Using code from [VB6 - Screen shot function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374540/vb6-screen-shot-function), you should be able to get a valid value from `GetPixel` using something like this:

```
Dim Pixel As Long
Dim Left As Long
Dim Top As Long
Dim hDC As Long

' Get Desktop window
hDC = GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow)

' Use size of screen
Left = Me.Left \ Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
Top = Me.Top \ Screen.TwipsPerPixelY

Pixel = GetPixel(hDC, Left, Top)
```

This will give you a [COLORREF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/colorref) from which you can extract the color of the pixel at the top left of your form.

You will need to Declare the following functions in a Module:

```
Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
```

You can then extract the RGB values from that pixel using the following functions:

```
Function GetRedValue(ByVal color As Long) As Long
    GetRedValue = color And &HFF&
End Function
 
Function GetGreenValue(ByVal color As Long) As Long
    GetGreenValue = (color \ &H100&) And &HFF&
End Function
 
Function GetBlueValue(ByVal color As Long) As Long
    GetBlueValue = (color \ &H10000) And &HFF&
End Function
```

Comment: @amin if this answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted using the checkmark to the left of the question.